# Is there a service in AWS that is equivalent to docker configs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm

I have a WordPress site that is gonna be hosted using ECS in AWS.

To make the management even more flexible, I plan not to store service configurations (i.e. php.ini, nginx.conf) inside the docker image itself. I found that docker swarm offers "docker configs" for such. Are there any equivalent tools doing the same thing? (I know AWS Secrets Manager can handle docker secrets though)

Any advice or alternative approaches? thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most similar you could use is probably [AWS SSM Parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html)

You will need some logic to retrieve the values when you are running the image.

- If you don't want to have the files also inside of the running containers, then you pull from Parameter Store, and add them to the environment, and you will need to do probably some work in the application to read from the environment (the application stays decoupled from the actually source of the config), or you can read directly from Param store in the application (easier, but you have some coupling in your image with Parameter store.
- if your concern is only about not having the values in the image, but it is fine if they are inside of the running container, then you can read from Param Store and inject the values in the container inside of the usual location of the files, so for the application is transparent

**As additional approaches:**

- Especially for `php.ini` and `nginx.conf` I like a simple approach that is having a separate `git` repo, with different config files per different environments.

  - You have a common docker image regardless of the environment
  - in build time, you pull the proper file for the enviroment, and either save as env variables, or inject in the container
- And last: need to mention classic tools like [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) or [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/), and also [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). More complex and maybe overkill

Answer (score 0):

The two ways that I store configs and secrets for most services are

- [Credstash](https://github.com/fugue/credstash) which is combination of `KMS` and `Dynamodb`, and
- `Parameter Store` which has already been mentioned,

The `aws command line tool` can be used to fetch from Parameter Store
   and `S3`(for configs), while `credstash` is its own utility (quite useful and easy to
   use) and needs to be installed separately.